# The NDK build is not working on Windows: "unable to find the specified path"

Tags: android-ndk

I'm building an Android application that requires the Android NDK.
When I try to execute the command *ndk-build.cmd*, I get the following error:

> unable to find the specified path

I've set the [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) to the path where the NDK is located, but it still doesn't work... How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What error messages do you see when you run `c:\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build.cmd`? Also, make sure that path to ndk does not contain spaces (e.g. don't put it in `C:\Program Files`

Comment: Do you want to build this file from Cygwin or command prompt or Eclipse?

Comment: If my response answers the question it would be nice to give it a green tick

Answer (score 0):

The binaries you need to add to the path are in the NDK itself.  I think I had the same problem as you, which I solved by adding *{NDK install dir}/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin* to my path.

I've written [a blog post](http://workingmatt.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/set-up-android-sdk-and-ndk.html) about my experiences of installing ADT/NDK. This solution appears about half way through.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the Linux terminal or use [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).

Or check out *[Setting Up Android JNI/NDK Projects in Windows Eclipse – And Sequoyah](http://permadi.com/blog/2011/09/setting-up-android-jni-projects-in-windows-eclipse-and-sequoyah/)*.

Comment: with cygwin I got this error:

ERROR: You are using a non-Cygwin compatible Make program.
Currently using: C:/cygwin/bin/make

To solve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
   NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later!

2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in:

     export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make